# Invalid type 'String' for field 'id' in existing Realm file

Tags: java, android, realm

I got a realm database going.

```
@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private String type;
private byte[] file;
```

With their respective getters and setters.

I'm trying to add a record to that database by the following command:

```
    try {
        loadRealm(); // Realm.init(context) and myRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
        myRealm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
            SolicitationDatabase solicitationDatabase = myRealm.createObject(SolicitationDatabase.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            solicitationDatabase.setType(mMainVariables.getType());
            solicitationDatabase.setFile(new byte[0]); //This should be empty, I'm only storing a file IF a file is found.
        });
    } finally {
        if(myRealm != null) {
            myRealm.close();
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
05-22 16:32:11.151 30366-30366/com.example.ga.realm3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.example.ga.realm3, PID: 30366
                                                                   io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Invalid type 'String' for field 'id' in existing Realm file.
                                                                       at io.realm.SolicitationDatabaseRealmProxy.validateTable(SolicitationDatabaseRealmProxy.java:605)
                                                                       at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.validateTable(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:56)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to having changed id from int to String.

I uninstalled the app on the device, ran it again and it worked.

Comment: In the future, use `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` or write a migration step.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the development phase, you shoul add `.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` to your `RealmConfiguration`. Once in production, you will need a migration step when you modify a model class in order for your users not loosing data when upgrading the app.